# Simulating very high loads using ApacheBench (ab)

Tags: webserver, benchmarking, apachebench

Is it possible to simulate very high (~30k concurrent requests) using apache bench. I increased my ulimit to 30k and then load tested my server using `ab -n 60000 -c 30000 ...`. Sometimes, I get receive exceptions on ab.  But, the number of requests that ab is posting to my server is greater than what I am specifying (I monitored my server stats, it is getting greater than 60k requests). Why am I getting this weird behaviour?

Comment: Why jmeter tag? Are you using JMeter and how?